# Please help, no back light anymore. MacBook pro won't boot

Tags: boot, macbook, backlight, moklistrt

Okay, a newbie here with a big problem.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my 2009 MacBook Pro.
I am completely new to the world of Linux and have yet to discover everything.
However, I could not dim the backlight of my MacBook. I come across several tips on the internet.
Now I have run the below and restarted. (See Screenshot)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSyxX.jpg)

However, now my backlight switches off during start-up and I can no longer see / do anything. I don't know if it is frozen or something like that because the keyboard backlight is no longer responding. And he did before.

I previously had that my screen first showed the following at startup:
"Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Could not create mokListRT: Invalid Parameter
Importing MOK states has failed: import_mok_state () failed: Invalid Parameter
Continuing boot since secure mode is disabled. "

I then replaced shimx64.efi with grubx64.efi by running the following:

"sudo su -

cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu

cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi

reboot"

This indeed ensures that this message is no longer visible. However, what strikes me is that now at start-up the screen briefly shows a black screen with a white dash. Then the screen turns off. This takes a while (starting up with this creature takes an average of 1.5 minutes to 2 minutes.
Then the screen briefly shows an NVidia logo. It disappears again and only after that I get to see my desktop and Ubuntu is ready for use.

But now after adding the lines shown in the attachment, it seems that the program is stucked or something...
Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I solved the above problem by installing ubuntu fresh. And then do not have the drivers installed automatically, but do this yourself later. Problem seems to come from NVidia. By not installing this I no longer have the above problems.
The MokList message, I have left it for what it is. It cannot cause any further problems.

But what I do run into is the enormous heat development in the macbook.
standard I already measure an average of 72 degrees Celsius in core 1 and core 2. When I stream a movie from my NAS, the temperature rose above 90 degrees Celsius. The fan will then run at full volume. A little later I see the temperature again towards 72 degrees Celsius. But this is still very high. Especially when almost no tasks are being performed. Someone here experience more in combination with a MacBook Pro?

Edit:
Now I am a bit worried about the temperature.
As long as I have no other applications open, the temperature of the CPU is already above 70 degrees Celsius.
And in some cases there are peaks of up to 96 degrees Celsius. This is really too warm and I don't expect any long-term preservation of the hardware with this.
I would like to hear if this can be solved properly.
From the following site I have executed point 1 (TLP) and point 2 (thermald).
https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/
What can I do now?

https://i.ibb.co/dKm39fb/Schermafdruk-van-2021-05-04-20-29-32.png